# Initialize SELECT2 dropdown with OPTGROUP in C# Webform

Tags: c#, jquery-select2

I've searched high and low for an exact example for how to populate a `<select>` control with `<optgroup>`, but I get various results. The documentation on select2.org states that the format should be like this:

```
  {
  "results": [
    { 
      "text": "Group 1", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "text": "Option 1.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "text": "Option 1.2"
        }
      ]
    },
    { 
      "text": "Group 2", 
      "children" : [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "Option 2.1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "text": "Option 2.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

But my results throw an error stating that the 'ID' field is not present. I think it's due to the way I'm initializing the `<select>`, but I don't see another way.

First, my data is being pulled from a MS SQL db using a stored procedure. I don't have easy control over the data format, so I'm using Linq to create an object I then initialize the `<select>` with using .DataBind(). Here is the relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="MySelect" name="myselect" runat="server"></select>
```

**Definitions for Parent and Child:**

```
public class Parent : Child
{
    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

**Linq statement:**

```
var parents = myData
    .Select(c => new Parent()
    {
        text = string.Format("{0} {1}", c.first_name, c.last_name),
        id = c.ID.ToString(),
        children = GetChildren(locations, c)
    })
    .ToArray();

    // Convert to JSON
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        results = parents
    });
```

**Linq result converted to JSON:**

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "text":"Parent 1 ",
         "children":[  
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"39",
         "text":"Parent 2",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "text":"Child 2.1",
               "id":"62",
               "Custom1":"196.00"
            },
            {  
               "text":"Child 2.2",
               "id":"130",
               "Custom1":"642.00"
            },
            {  
               "text":"Child 2.2",
               "id":"61",
               "Custom1":"0.00"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"15",
         "text":"Parent 3",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "text":"Child 3.1",
               "id":"13",
               "Custom1":"40.00"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**DataBind:**

```
MySelect.DataSource = json;
MySelect.DataValueField = "id";
MySelect.DataTextField = "text";
MySelect.DataBind();
```

After all of this, the MySelect `<select>` renders with a dropdown containing only the parents and no `<optgroup>` elements in the actual HTML.

I have tried excluding the 'id' member from the `<Parent>` class, but then there is an error thrown from the .DataBind() that there is no 'id' even though the children all have ids.

I suspect that using .DataBind() isn't the way to handle this. I want to keep the code clean, short and quick.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: try to remove the `id` from the parent

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch I have done that, but then I receive an error from .DataBind() that the 'id' field does not exist.

Comment: I think the solution I need is how to populate the HTML select with the results of my Linq query without using .DataBind() which is stumbling on the absence of `id` on the parent items.